# How to add an inline background image?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert a static html page into a rails page.

How would I convert the following line

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(../../foo.png);">
```

The image is inside the `assets/images` folder.

If it were a standard image and not a background image I would use an `image_tag`.

Is it better to remove the inline styling into the css file? If so how would the css look?

```
.item .active {
background-image: url(assets/foo.png);
}
```

Comment: exactly right... writing styles into external css file is considered good practice for many reasons.

Comment: It's right. Any issues you are facing?

Comment: either use `.item` or `.active` classes to apply the css.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to separate the css code so you can reuse it in the future.
You can have it this way...

```
.item.active {
    background-image: image_url("foo.png");
 }
```

no need to type the `/assets/` and don't forget to do `rake assets:precompile`

for advantages and disadvantages of inline and external use of css, [click here](https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/inline-vs-internal-vs-external-css/)

Answer (score 1):

From this

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(../../foo.png);">
```

the css would be

```
.item.active {
    background-image: image_url("foo.png");
 }
```

This indicates that the div has **both** classes. It may not be what you are after as we don't know your specific circumstances.

It may be that the image only applies to the `.active` class or just the `.item` class.

Then the CSS would be just include a **single** class name such as

```
.active {
    background-image: image_url("foo.png");
 }
```

This

```
.item .active {
    background-image: image_url("foo.png");
 }
```

is for when the `.active` class is a **descendant** of the `.item` class,

Comment: your answer is well explained. :)